# React must call with setTimeout to update view correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm making modifications to this file https://github.com/davidguttman/react-pivot/blob/master/index.jsx#L84 to move the `Dimensions` component out to a parent component.

One strange thing i noticed is that i have to call `setTimeout(this.updateRows, 0)` instead of `this.updateRows()` for the views to update correctly.

Any idea why this is so? AFAIK, `setTimeout(_,0)` simply makes the function call asynchronous (i.e. allows concurrent execution for performance). Why would that help with rendering views correctly? I'm asking this question to avoid "Programming by Coincidence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`setState` is asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Since you are reading from `this.state` in the `updateRows` function, it won't work until the state is actually updated.
Using `setTimeout` as you did, is one way to allow the state to update. `setState` will complete, and then `updateRows` will execute in the next frame.

A better way would be to use the callback parameter of `setState`

```
this.setState({dimensions: updatedDimensions}, () => {
  this.updateRows();
});
```

Another option is to keep any state changes in an object and pass it into the function instead of reading directly from `this.state`, but this can lead to much more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance it's probably less about "concurrent execution" and more about the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). The `setTimeout` call removes function execution from the current call stack and adds an entry to the message queue. The currently executing stack will run to completion before the next message in the queue begins execution.

I don't know why this is required in this particular instance - some sort of state must be getting set in the current stack that's required for `updateRows` to produce the desired result.